# Variadic macros arguments

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have an assert macros which looks like:

```
#define ASSERT(condition, ...) \
  (condition) ? (void)0 : MyLogFunction(__LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

`MyLogFunction` is a variadic template too:

```
template<typename... Args>
void MyLogFunction(int line, const Args&... args) {/*code*/}
```

Everything works well except the case when I don't want to insert additional information into assert call.

So this works nice:

```
ASSERT(false, "test: %s", "formatted");
```

But this isn't:

```
ASSERT(false);
```

I believe there is a way to handle situation when no variadic args has has been passed into macro call and there is a way to insert something like simple string `""` instead of `__VA_ARGS__`

Comment: C++11 adds variadic argument lists for macros.  It stipulates that there shall be at least one argument corresponding to the ellipsis (ISO/IEC 14882:2011 §16.3 Macro Replacement, ¶4, ¶12).  It is likely that GCC provides alternatives (`gcc` has non-standard mechanisms to handle 0 variable arguments, so `g++` probably does too), but it isn't standard.  I recommend always providing a value: `ASSERT(false, "false");` as it is portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a solution for the macros, but a simple workaround would be to provide a helper variadic function template, which can get 0 parameters and do the condition checking there:

```
#define ASSERT(...) \
  MyLogHelper(__LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)

template<typename... Args>
void MyLogFunction(int line, const Args&... ) {/*code*/}

template<typename... Args>
void MyLogHelper(int line, bool condition, const Args&... args)
{
    if (!condition) MyLogFunction(line,args...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable way to do it.
Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_macro